# Set-theoretic geology: controlled erosion?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, forcing

I have to say that after the two last posts by Timothy Chow on Forcing I got so intrigued that I am trying to rethink the little I know about this formidable chapter of mathematics.

I have also to add that, although aware of the new field of **set-theoretic geology**, I am far from having a full grasp of it, so pre-emptive apologies to experts if I ask something that is either trivial or false.

Onto the point. Suppose I start from a transitive model of set theory $M$, and, rather than trying to expand it, I would rather do something opposite, namely the following: given an element $G$ of the model, try to "yank it out", to remove it surgically so that what remains is still a transitive model $M_0$.

In other words, try to establish $M= M_0[G]$.

Of course things are not so easy: I want to eliminate $G$ from $M$, but obviously I have to get rid of a lot of other sets in $M$ which are associated to $G$, for instance other sets which would imply its existence. Moreover, I have to choose judiciously whether or not $G$ is removable in such a way that after its removal (and of  its "peers" ) the remaining set is still a model of $ZF$ of the same ordinal height.

I would call this operation **selective erosion** (if there is a canonical name for this operation please supply it) .

I  understand that this may not be possible in some scenarios: for instance if $M$ is the minimal model, it is too "skinny" to allow for removals. But, unless intuition  fails me, there should be plenty of "fat" models which should be liable to erosion.

MOTIVE

The way I look at this scenario is kind of the **reciprocal of forcing**: I would like  to yank out some  specific $G$ which codes some specific  truths in $M$, for instance get rid of  some map which collapses some cardinals.

QUESTION:

> Are there methods that can be employed to do the surgery I sketched
> ? Notice that I do not ask whether a model is liable to erosion, rather whether some specific sets  can be removed, and if so how.

NOTE: if I already  know that $M$ is a forcing extension by $G$, then the problem is already trivially solved. Rather, suppose I only know that $M$ is a transitive model and someone comes along and gives me a $G$ in the model, and asks: is $G$ removable? I want to answer yes or no. Again, in some particular case the negative answer is obvious (example if G is an ordinal in $M$). But what about less trivial cases?

**ADDENDUM**: After the comments of Asaf, and especially after the great first answer by Jonas, time to take stock: The first thing that comes to my mind is that there are at least TWO candidate strategies to tackle this problem (and perhaps neither of them is the good one). You can call them BOTTOM-UP, which is the one I have sketched very loosely in my "debate" with Asaf, and the one which I would call TOP-DOWN which is the one advocated by Jonas.

Let us briefly recap them:

1. **BOTTOM UP**. Start from a minimal model  $W_0$ such that $A\notin W$ (for instance the constructibles in $M$) , and look at the  set of  extensions $W$ of the bottom $W_0$  such that $W[A] \neq M$, ordered by inclusion,  then try to take the *colimit of this ordered set* (in other words, you hope that the sup of all of them is a model and does not contain A, but adding A you get M) . Is such a beast exists you found your A-eroded M
2. **TOP DOWN** See Jonas's answer (I would call it the "*take the limit* " method).

Notice that both could be considered a form of selective geology:

1 is like growing the "earth", from some core, till a layer where A is present is reached.

2 is actually more in line with erosion, getting rid of as much as you can, as so aptly Jonas said.

So, either going from non A-grounds and looking for their union, or from A-grounds and looking for their intersection

**PROBLEM**: Both methods rely on looking at a certain ordered set of models of ZF in the "universe' M, and on certain lattice operations which can be performed. I have absolutely no clue whether such operations (taking sups or infs) are admitted in all cases (my gut feeling is no).

The story continues....

Comment: Your question and the terminology "selective erosion" suggest that you want the submodel $M_0$ to be in some sense close to $M$. Otherwise, you could simply say that $G$ is yankable iff it's not in the minimal model, and the result of yanking is the minimal model. But in what sense should $M_0$ be close to $M$? The same ordinals? Then you can yank any $G$ that isn't in $L^{(M)}$. Maybe $M$ should be a forcing-extension of $M_0$? More specifically, a forcing extension by re-adjoining $G$? Or maybe $M$ should satisfy some form of the covering lemma over $M_0$? Or maybe $\dots$?

Comment: If you weren't here already to help me either tuning my often sloppy questions, or "yank them out" altogether, I should pay you to do so. So, let me be a bit more precise: YES, the idea is to get M_0 as close as possible to M (hence the name, I could have as well called judicious surgery) Secondly, I do not just want to "peel off" anything, rather suppose taht someone (say the devil) comes up to you and say: Andreas, you have this wonderful M. Let me pick a set in  it, say G. Now, you have to tell me if this set is yankable or not, meaning that I can yank it out,

Comment: take out also a minimal set of sets in M which are related to G, in such as way that after that I end up with a transitive submodel of M  of the same height and moreover if I throw in G back, close with respect to definable operations,  again BANG! I get M. Now, it is clear to me that tons of Gs are not yankable, right? But some possibly are. So, again, think of this as putting a MINUS sign to forcing: M+ G = M[G], now the equatin  would be : M -G is a M_0 such that M_0[G] = M. Kind of an inverse operation

Comment: Post Scriptum I am sure you already see where I am trying to go. The inverse of forcing, or "selective erosion"< assuming of course that is feasible and not trivial, would play the reversal role of forcing: rather than judiciously "fattening" a model a bit, and add new facts unknown to the ground model (but "true" outside) here you would like to have a method for removing facts from a model. Some kind of inner model construction to obliterate some facts from your initial model

Comment: Possibly related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/291088/622

Comment: @AsafKaragila Todah Rabbah! Yes, it is related, especially your answer there. Now, problem  is, we do not know if there is an inner model inside, although in fact we do (the constructibel minimal model) . Now, M_minimal is definitely inside M, but perhaps it is too "thin". But we may be able to salvage your idea: how about expanding M_minimal  by forcing extensions all the while remaining inside M? If we are lucky, at some point we may meet G, in which case we win. But I suspect there are situations in which there is an ascending chain inside M, and none contains G...

Comment: elaborating this idea a bit further: M_minimal , M1, M2,..... etc all forcing extensions of the previous one. What one would like to see is whether  our G is reachable by this chain.Even if it is, though, there is an issue: the extension which contains G may not reach the "crust" of M...

Comment: emendation to what I have said: actually, if G appears at some point of the expansion, it is certainly removable, but unless it is so to speak in the outermost boundaries of the expansion, it will not qualify to describe M as M_0[G] for some M_0 submodel of M. It is, so to speak, "buried inside some layer of  M".

Comment: In general, there's no reason to expect a minimal model. In $L[0^\#]$, for example, I don't believe there is a maximal model without $0^\#$ itself. Or even adding a Cohen real, there's no reason to expect a maximal model where "only the Cohen real is missing", because you will therefore still want the Cohen real restricted to various subsets of $\omega$.

Comment: You might find the notion of grounds and mantle relevant here.  It’s a nontrivial result that the statement “V is a set-generic extension of some inner model” is actually first-order expressible, and moreover, the intersection of all such inner models, the mantle, is also first-order definable.  Usuba proved that the intersection of set-many grounds is itself a ground.

Comment: Asaf, I apologize for my ignorance, but are you saying that if I start from $M =L[0^\#]$  L truncated to M is not a model of ZF?

Comment: @MonroeEskew as I mentioned in the question, I am a newbie in Set Theoretical Geology, but I do know a few fact, like the ones you mentioned (not their proof!) by reading a nice slides intro. Definitely relevant. I hope some expert will chime in (included you and Asaf) to tell me what can be done and what is unknown. Meanwhile, thanks to you both for the useful comments

Comment: @Mirco: I don't really understand your question. My point is that there is no *maximal* model without $0^\#$. You said that you want to avoid removing "too many sets". Going all the way down to $L$ is going to remove *a lot* of sets that you could have kept.

Comment: @Asaf, sorry I was not clear. What I meant is not to erode till I get to L, rather, I want to have a ground INSIDE M to start my campaign, and if this ground exists, grow it (add forcing layers) in the hope that at some point I stumble upon my selected G. Notice that assuming that there is a ground, there are many ascending chains of forcing extensions, and so I will have to be able to see if G gets intercepted in any of them. Makes sense?

Comment: Well, then let's go to the case of $L[c]$ where $c$ is a Cohen real.

Comment: If by that you mean M = L[c]  then obviously the case G= c is trivial: Just define M_0 = L (relativized to M) and we are done. If G is not c, then it is not so trivial, at least to me. Intuitively, the simple minded approach would work is G has , so to speak, the same definability strength of c.: c is in L[G] and conversely.

Comment: But you removed too much. You can keep the subset of the Cohen real with the even coordinates. You can even save a large number of subsets, provided you're willing to forego the axiom of choice.

Comment: I see your point now. Well done. But, rather than deter me, this makes me even more confident that if you want to erode without taking out "too much", the best strategy would be to start from some basic ground, grow it in all possible ways as long as it does stay inside M, and just try to detect where and when G finally pops up.

Comment: So how would you erode $0^\#$ from $L[0^\#]$?

Comment: Answer: I would not erode it :) Rather, assuming there is a CORE (not a mantle, something much more solid, such a L itself restricted to M ) I would begin growing the core in all possible forcing directions (think of a directed lattice of extensions). Now, if I understand you (remember you are the set theorist, not I) , zero sharp is in none of the extensions in the lattice. What about then taking the minimal submodel of M which contains ALL the forcing extensions?

Comment: Two cases: either this fat submodel is M itself, in which case zero sharp is NOT erodable, or it is a proper submodel of M. In that case, I call it M_0 and add zero sharp. PS I would bet that the envelope of the lattice is M itself

Comment: Your bottom up really can't work. Suppose that $x$ is a generic real over $L[0^\#]$, make it even minimal, just for kicks. Now you want to remove $x$ from $L[0^\#,x]$. By minimality we even know what the result *must be*, $L[0^\#]$. But if you start with $L$, no matter what you do, you will never, ever, ever, reach $L[0^\#]$ by adding more and more generics.

Comment: Asaf, to begin with, even if your counterexample worked, it would simply imply that in SOME cases my bottom up method does not work, not that it "can't work". Basic logi. Secondly, if you have an answer to this question which goes beyond what Jonas has already put forward, I strongly invite you to post it. MO has already complained that our  back and forth goes beyond the standards of  acceptable comments, and suggested continuing the conversation in chat. If you wish to do it, bring the laser saber... :)

Comment: now, your counterexample:  let us say that we work in $M =L[0^\#, x]$ without knowing that it is a forcing extension of   $M =L[0^\#]$ and the devil chooses x. I consider the set of all submodels of M which are generic extensions of L and which omit x, ordered by inclusion. This set is not empty (trivial). Assume I take the UNION  of all of them. The union is exactly your friend, namely  $M =L[0^\#]$.

Comment: emendation: the set of all extensions of L which do not contain A AND such that their are  NOT A-grounds (in the sense specified by The answer)

Comment: Wait, are you claiming that $0^\#$ lies in some set generic extension of $L$?

Comment: You like cheap shots, don't you? No I do not claim that. What I claim is this: assume you start with $M =L[0^\#, x]$. You want to erode x from M, presumably reducing it to  $M =L[0^\#]$ . Now, let us call $ $M_0 =L[0^\#]$.  Now I want somehow reach M_0 from below. I believe that , one can express M_0 as a union of forcing extension , NOT as any one of them . PS This is my last reply to you as a comment: either you post an answer, I promise that if it is well written I will give you my vote, or light sabers in  private chat

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What a fantastic question, and thanks to Asaf and Mirco for the great discussion in comments!  I love the idea of “removing” a given set from a model of ZFC, to obtain a smaller model of ZFC - some kind of inner model method analogous to the outer model method of forcing.  This may not be a complete answer, but I think that geology does offer a useful framework for attacking this question, at least when the “erosion” is strictly due to forcing (the more general question, when is a set removable *at all* while leaving behind a model of the same height, can be answered I think by looking to see whether the set in question is in $L$).

(Recall from set-theoretic geology: an inner model $W$ is a ground of our universe V if it is a transitive proper class satisfying ZFC, such there exists $G \in V$ which is generic over $W$ and $W[G]=V$. The foundational theorem of geology says the grounds of $V$ form a uniformly first-order definable collection of inner models in $V$).

Given a candidate set $A\in V$, we can ask whether $A$ is forcing-erodable by asking “Is there a ground $W$ that omits $A$”?  Any such ground $W$ is a candidate for the model obtained by removing $A$ from $V$.

How do we identify a single, canonical inner model by removing $A$?  In contrast to forcing, in which we want add as little as possible to $V$ in order to obtain $V[G]$, here we are doing the inverse - I argue that we want to remove the absolute maximum possible from $V$, while *still retaining the property that everything we remove can be added back by adding $A$ itself*.

For example, given a Cohen extension  $V[c]$, we can eliminate $c$ by going to an inner model $V[c^\prime]$ that contains only the real $c^\prime$ that lies on the even digits of $c$... but this is unsatisfying, because although we removed $c$ it feels as though we only removed half of the information contained in $c$.  To “erode $c$”, we want to go all the way down to the inner model $V$.

Geology gives us an approach.  For a set $A \in V$, call a ground $W$ of $V$ an $A$-ground if:

1. $A\notin W$ (we are eroding $A$)
2. $W[A] =V$ (we are not going ‘too far’ - everything we remove can be added back by adding $A$)

Is there a minimal such $A$-ground?  I am not certain of the answer, but the natural candidate is the intersection of all $A$-grounds (let’s call this the $A$-mantle).

Questions:  If $M_A$ is the $A$-mantle, then

1. is $M_A$ an $A$-ground ?  If so, this is the right candidate for “eroding $A$ from $V$”.
2. If $M_A$ is not an $A$-ground, then is $M_A$ a model of ZFC?  If that is the case, then does $M_A[A]=V$?

These are analogous to the questions in geology “Is the Mantle a model of ZFC” and “Is the mantle necessarily a ground”.

Comment: Jonas, I have no time to read your answer now (but I will!). You already got my like for 1) taking the first stab 2) because I "smelled " your answer and it is definitely going where I would like it to go. Detailed comments forthcoming . Meanwhile I can tell you the REAL reason motivating my question (Siths never tell you their real agenda, but I suspect that Andreas had already understood, his is simply too good to fool ). My question is there because i want to really understand forcing, and by that I mean really really really. So I am trying first to understand its opposite :)

Comment: Removing AC from the equation is so much more interesting. Especially in the case of a Cohen real, where adding the one set will invariably add ***a lot*** of grounds (and over $L$ and other "small models" a proper class of them).

Comment: Thanks, @MircoA.Mannucci - this is something like my interest in this question as well.  The introduction to your question above pointed me in the direction of Timothy Chow's two recent questions about forcing - thank you, they were great reads and your answers were as well.

Comment: @AsafKaragila - I must admit, questions about forcing without AC seem like a terrible quagmire to me - but that just says I need to work more with models without choice!  Did I read your comment correctly - adding a Cohen real can add class-many grounds?

Comment: Will there generally be a proper class of A-grounds and is it ok to intersect them all in that case?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.04514, Yes, adding a Cohen real to L has a proper class of grounds. However their intersection is L. More interestingly, their union is a ZF model which is not a ground of the Cohen extension.

Comment: @jonasreitz my answer to your answer is in the ADDENDUM. Hopefully there will be more "digging", just to remain on geology...

Comment: @jonasreitz when u have a chance, take a look at my new "geological" question. Perhaps you have something to contribute there too. All the best, Mirco

Comment: @MircoA.Mannucci - just responded - great question!